# if else statement in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

What is the best way to handle class changes in jquery? As if a div changes class from being Active to not. Basically I am trying to append some code for when a div is active and when its not do something else

```
If div active {
    do this
}

When not active {

 do this

}
```

Comment: There isn't so much of a question here as a "how do I code this up".  What is your specific question?  What have you tried?  Is there an area of jQuery or CSS technology that is either specifically unclear or not functioning as you expect?

Comment: Not getting your requirement?? and  what is condition ??

Comment: Sorry going to edit the question

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the element has an `active` class using `.hasClass()`

```
if ($('section1').hasClass('active') || $('section2').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#fp-nav').animate({ "right": "0px" }, 2000 );
} else {
    $('#fp-nav').animate({ "right": "-155px" }, 2000 );
}
```